# adding an action to a QListWidget

Tags: c++, qt, action, qlistwidget

I try to add actions to an QListWidget like this:

```
toolItems = new QListWidget(this);
toolItems->addAction(ui->itemLight);
toolItems->addAction(ui->itemDarkLight);
toolItems->addAction(ui->itemCameraPos);
toolItems->addAction(ui->itemCamera);
toolItems->addAction(ui->itemRounded);
toolItems->addAction(ui->itemLightbulb);
toolItems->addAction(ui->itemCommentOnScreen);
```

But the problem is that this displays nothing, but all actions have text?! How I can fix this?

Comment: what would you like to achieve? Something like QMenu?

Comment: No, an list with items, when click on it doing the prefered action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is OK, because `QListWidget` does not support adding actions. You need to read documentation and to use [`QListWidget::addItem`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#addItem-2) method.

But you may create items from actions:

```
QListWidgetItem *createItemFromAction( const QAction* action )
{
  Q_ASSERT( action );
  QListWidgetItem *item = new QListWidgetItem();
  item->setText( action->text() );
  item->setToolTip( action->toolTip() );
  item->setIcon( action->icon() );
  // ...
  return item;
}
//...
toolItems->addAction( createItemFromAction( ui->itemCommentOnScreen ) );
```

Comment: @Jan and don't forget, that your base action may be modified, so then you need to catch `changed` signal and update your widget item.

Comment: btw, i get now an problem there: createItemFromAction was not declared in this scope. how i can fix this?

Comment: It just a sample. You should create it as a method. I think that you are asking about C++ basic things.